# Sound wave features correlated with speaker voice

Tags: audio, signal-processing

What are a few of the simplest features of a sound wave that are correlated with differences between voices of different speakers? Where can I find how to calculate these from data?

The project we're trying to solve takes 3 hours of audio as input, each moment of which has either one of two people talking or silence. We need to determine which of these alternatives each moment corresponds to using hmm.

The results don't have to be 100% accurate. An approximation will suffice.

Comment: How is this a problem w/ a program (as opposed to a problem to be solved BY a program)?

Comment: I know there are libraries/APIs like ALIZE and LIUM that can do this sort of thing automatically, but we're trying to see how far we get anyway. The solution is not important. The important thing is to see how far we can get by ourselves. Is that absolutely out of the question? Any help would be appreciated.